# Find the $\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{1}{n^2}\cdot \sum_{k=1}^{n}k\cdot \ln\left(1+\frac{3k}{n}\right)$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, sequences-and-series, limits

> $$\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{1}{n^2}\cdot \sum_{k=1}^{n}k\cdot \ln\left(1+\frac{3k}{n}\right)$$

How should I approach this this? to find the limit? to find if the series converge?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By writing 
$$
\frac{1}{n^2}\cdot \sum_{k=1}^{n}k\cdot \ln\left(1+\frac{3k}{n}\right)=\frac{1}{n}\cdot \sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{k}{n}\cdot \ln\left(1+3\cdot\frac{k}{n}\right)
$$ one may recognize a Riemann sum, then as $n \to \infty$,
$$
\frac1n \sum_{k=1}^nf\left(\frac kn\right) \to \int_0^1f(x)dx.
$$

---

You are led to evaluate $\displaystyle \int_0^1 \!\!x \ln(1+3x)dx$, which one may obtain by integrating by parts:

> $$
> \begin{align}
> \int_0^1x \ln(1+3x)\:dx&=\left[\frac{x^2}2\:\ln(1+3x)\right]_0^1-\frac32\int_0^1 \frac{x^2}{1+3x}\:dx
> \\\\&=\ln 2-\frac12\int_0^1 \left(x-\frac13+\frac1{3(1+3x)} \right)dx
> \\\\&=\ln 2-\frac12\left[\frac{x^2}2-\frac x3+\frac19\:\ln(1+3x)\right]_0^1
> \\\\&=\frac89\ln 2-\frac1{12}.
> \end{align}
> $$

Comment: So the integral is $\int_{0}^{1} x*ln(1+3x)dx$?

Comment: @newhere Exactely. You may use an integration by parts to get the result.